# position fixed images within div (pins on map)

Tags: html, css, xhtml, stylesheet

I have a "map" div with the css rules `height: 400px; width: 800px; background: url(map.png)`.  This div has a background image of a world map.  I have some images that act as "pins" that I want to place on the map in specific areas.  What CSS properties would I give the image to be able to, for example, place them within the "map" div by specific top/left pixel coordinates of the "map" div?  I am able to position them relative to the entire body but not to the specific div.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put position: relative on the map div, then put position: absolute on the pins. Using :

```
left: 10px;
top: 10px;
position: absolute;
```

on the pins, while they are contained by the map div, which has position relative, would put the pins in the top left corner. I hope this is clear enough...

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do is put them inside the `map` div, give `#map { position: relative; }` and then give the pins `position: absolute;` with `top` and `left` properties (probably what you're already doing).

If it's impossible to put the pins in the `map` itself, you can do the same thing with a container div:

```
<div id="map-wrapper">
    <div id="map">...</div>
    <!-- pins -->
</div>
```

Either way, the point is that `absolute` positioning is relative to the nearest parent that has `position: relative;` That's the `body` by default, but you can give the property to any other element you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using `position: absolute`. It will position itself relative to the first *relative* positioned parent. So make sure the map element in which the pins are created is set to `position: relative`. Example:

```
#map {
  position: relative;
}

#pin_a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

You can use top, bottom, right, left.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `position: relative;` on the map. This will not affect the map div positioning but will establish a containing block for its children. With this done you will be able to position the market with `position:absolute;` and `left/right`. Their position will be computed from relative to the top,left corner of the map div.

See here for a full reference on containing blocks and positioning: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details